# type of sampling required

Tags: sampling

I have to write a commentary on an article about R-E-A-D dogs and their effect on reading ability in children.

The article says that for this study 19 children entering the second grade were recruited from the local primary school to participate in the study. Recruitment was conducted through flyers at the two local primary schools and the library.

Is this procedure random sampling method or volunteering sampling, as it seems participants can choose whether theey want to reply to the flyers or not. I am not sure.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It is **not random** since only some people take flyers. this is one of the problems of social studies, picking the sample that represents the population is really hard.

You have here two problems:

1. **Only some people take the flyers**
2. The recollection of information is **geographically biased**